runtime error 9 when pushing new array elements
I have a workbook with descriptive numbered sheet names. I need to populate an array with the numbers I extract from the sheet names. I am getting a runtime error 9 subscript out of range when I try adding new array elements. There are only 111 worksheets in the workbook so I'm nowhere near overflowing the array. I've tried declaring Dim haystack (1 To 111) but that didn't work.
Dim num As Integer
Dim newEntry As String
Dim haystack() As String
Dim wsCount As Integer

wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For num = 1 To wsCount
    newEntry = Mid(Worksheets(num).Name, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") + 1, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, ")") - InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") - 1)
    If IsNumeric(newEntry) Then
        haystack(num) = newEntry 'this line throws an error
    End If
Next num 


Depending on whether you are using 0 based or 1 based arrays you would use Dim haystack(110) or Dim haystack(111)
Alternatively once you know wsCount you could use Redim haystack(wsCount)

You need the declaration once. Edit only (1 To 111) in your third line of the code.

You might find this learning resource useful https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

Please, try this way. It uses a second variable (k) to avoid having empty array elements:
Sub fillSheetsName()
  Dim num As Long, newEntry As String, haystack() As String, wsCount As Integer, k As Long, arr

  wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
  ReDim haystack(1 To wsCount): k = 1
  For num = 1 To wsCount
    If InStr(Worksheets(num).name, "(") > 0 And InStr(Worksheets(num).name, "(") > 0 Then _
        newEntry = Split(Split(Worksheets(num).name, "(")(1), ")")(0) 'it extracts what is between parenthesis
        If IsNumeric(newEntry) Then
            haystack(k) = newEntry: k = k + 1 'to not have empty elements (for cases where newEntry is not numeric)
            newEntry = ""
        End If
  Next num
  ReDim Preserve haystack(1 To k - 1)
  Debug.Print UBound(haystack)       'how many such numbers have been extracted
  Debug.Print Join(haystack, vbCrLf) 'see in Immediate Window the array content
End Sub


Thanks, this fixed it. The problem was no error checking: I failed to check for parentheses and not all worksheet names had them. With this code though, for cases where newEntry wan't numeric, it did populate the array with the last numeric entry so there are a few collisions. No biggie, I'll sort it out. Thanks again for saving me hours of debugging.

@andreithegiant Not sure I correctly understand what "for cases where newEntry wan't numeric, it did populate the array with the last numeric entry" means. Does it return the numeric part of the string between parenthesis? What "collisioins" should mean in the code context? Do you need unique values and does it return all cases, even if duplicate exists? Can you give an example? I am sure that it can be handled in code. Of course, if I understand what is it about...

there are tabs named Invoice(1), . . ., Invoice(76), followed by 3 alpha tab names Fu, Bar, etc. When it finished the last numeric tab, Invoice(76), it will populate the array with value 76 3x (i.e. k is incremented and previous value is duplicated (i.e. collision)).

@andreithegiant I do not think that the process happens as you try describing it... Most probable, there are more cases for the same numeric value. I mean, "Invoice(76)" , "Something (76)" and "Test(76)". If you want the code to skip the following ones, I mean to not allow duplicates, I can adapt it to do it. If you want/try explaining about a different issue, please give an eloquent example. I do not understand too much from what you tried exemplifying... It was based on your assumption, which I am afraid is not a correct one.

There are only 111 tabs so it is easy to verify that there are no tabs with duplicate numerical values. However, those 3 alpha tabs contain no parentheses (i.e. Fu, Bar instead of Invoice(i)), so it doesn't enter into the 1st If condition in the for loop. But it looks like it's entering the 2nd if and carrying over the last value for newEntry. I will try nesting the 2nd If in the first & see if that doesn't fix it.

@andreithegiant Yes, I looked to the code and you are right! I missed to reinitialize the newEntry variable... Please, test the updated answer and send some feedback.

There, I nested the 2nd If and now it works right! Thanks for all the help!

No need to nest anything. A second if only slows down the code speed, after the mentioned update...

I try to avoid redim preserve because of the overhead.
Also note that I use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook to avoid confusing the macro in case you have more than one workbook open.
I suggest:
Option Explicit

Sub marine()
Dim num As Integer
Dim newEntry As String
Dim haystack() As String

ReDim haystack(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
For num = 1 To UBound(haystack)
    newEntry = Mid(Worksheets(num).Name, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") + 1, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, ")") - InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") - 1)
    If IsNumeric(newEntry) Then
        haystack(num) = newEntry
    End If
Next num
End Sub

If you don't mind having haystack typed as a variant (the contents will still be strings), but you don't want to have empty entries, you can use the ArrayList object, which has a simple method of copying to a variant array.
You could also use a Collection or Dictionary object, but the code would be a bit longer.
Sub merge()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newEntry As String
Dim haystack() As Variant
Dim arrHaystack As Object

Set arrHaystack = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        newEntry = Mid(.Name, InStr(.Name, "(") + 1, InStr(.Name, ")") - InStr(.Name, "(") - 1)
    End With
    If IsNumeric(newEntry) Then
        arrHaystack.Add newEntry
    End If
Next ws

haystack = arrHaystack.toarray

End Sub



See VBA ArrayList - A Complete Guide for more details on that method.

Ron Rosenfeld: still getting the same error either way. But I do love your sub names, gonna start naming mine sub sume() and sub ject().

@andreithegiant I'm surprised. No errors here. I wonder what's going on. Which line is returning the error?

sorry, your code should work but for my original error, as ably fixed by FaneDuru's error handling, which was that not all tab names contained parentheses. That threw an error. Thanks for your help though and sorry for sending you on a wild goose chase.

Try this code:
Sub Test()

    Dim num As Integer
    Dim newEntry As String
    Dim haystack As Variant
    Dim wsCount As Integer
    
    wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For num = 1 To wsCount
        newEntry = Mid(Worksheets(num).Name, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") + 1, InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, ")") - InStr(Worksheets(num).Name, "(") - 1)
        If IsNumeric(newEntry) Then
            If IsEmpty(haystack) Then
                ReDim haystack(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve haystack(UBound(haystack) + 1)
            End If
            haystack(num - 1) = newEntry
        End If
    Next num

End Sub

